# There exist atmost one finite field (upto isomorphism) of any given order: true or false?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is  the following statement true or false:

There exists at most one finite field (up to isomorphism) of any given order.

I think this statement is false,  because  I know that  $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field if $p$ is prime, but $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$  will not be a field  if  $n = 4,6,8, \ldots$

Is that correct?

Comment: Note that the fact $\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$ is not a field does not imply there can't be some other ring which is a field with four elements. And, in fact, there is a field of four elements.

Comment: Note that the statement says "at most one" i.e. zero or one. Just because there is no finite field of order 6 (for example) does not make the statement false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true. You can visit [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field). Notice that if $p$ and $q$ are two different primes, $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\mathbb Z_q$ have different offer, so the statement doesn't apply here. Your statement says that there exists only one (up to isomorphism) finite field of order $p$, and that this result can be applied to every $p$. I guess you are thinking that there is only one finite field, which is obviously false as you have pointed out.